# ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_FAILED, resolution=null, message=null}

Tags: google-api-client

In my project I want to create file on Google Drive. I created API key for my project and add it into Manifest file. But when i connect googleapiclient using `googleapiclient.connect()` it gives

```
error.ConnectionResult{statusCode=SIGN_IN_FAILED, resolution=null,message=null}
```

inside `onConnectionFailed`.
Please give solution for above problem

Comment: Do you need to register the credentials with google before calling the API perhaps?

Comment: sir, I Already done with credentials